# When is an ordinary differential equation truly inexact?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

An exact ordinary differential equation is one of the form:

$$M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0\tag{1}$$

where we must have that

$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}\tag{2}$$

This is equivalent to saying that there is an underlying potential function whose total derivative gives the differential equation (1). When we have an ordinary differential equation of the form (1) that does not satisfy (2), we say that it is inexact. However what we normally do is realize that if we cleverly multiply the entire equation (1) by a function $\mu(x,y)$, called an "integrating factor", we can actually make the equation exact. In a sense, this seems to indicate to me that it actually was exact all along, just not *manifestly* exact.

Is there a way to tell whether or not a differential equation of the form (1) is *truly* inexact, i.e. there exists no such integrating factor $\mu$ that will make it exact? Of course, I'm restricting my attention to well-behaved functions $M$ and $N$.

Comment: This problem amouts to find a function $\mu$ s.t. $\mu alpha$ is a closed differential 1-form, for $\alpha$ a differential 1-form. We have $d(\mu \alpha) = d\mu \wedge \alpha + \mu d \alpha$. Equating this to zero gives you a differential equation on $\mu$. Did you look at that equation ?

Comment: If you suppose $\mu>0$, this amounts to find $f$ s.t. $0=df\wedge \alpha + d\alpha$ where $f=\ln \mu$.

Comment: Look here : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227799/existance-of-integrating-factors-a-constructive-proof/227811

Comment: Integrating factor always exists, at least locally.